# Awk Script for fastText vectors - Error: "unexpected character 0xe2" when there's no such character

Tags: vector, awk, fasttext

I ran the following Awk script to get fastText vectors on my Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish).
However, I always get the same error code: **awk: lines 5 and 13: unexpected character 0xe2**

## The Awk script that combines a .txt wordlist into a file with vectors:

```
$ awk -f combine.awk 

BEGIN{

 infile = "adjectives.txt"
 while (getline < infile > 0) {
   INCLUDE[$1]=1
 } 
 close(infile)
 
 infile = "cc.en.300.vec"
 outfile = "fasttextvectors_adjectives.txt"
 system("rm " outfile)
 while (getline < infile > 0) {
   if ($1 in INCLUDE) print >> outfile
 } 
 close(infile)
 close(outfile)
 


}
```

**I suspect there is something in the Awk script code itself, but I have seen someone use the same script in their Mac and being able to run it. Is it something about Ubuntu?

I've already tried:**

- Making sure word list **doesn't** contain words with special characters at all;
- Changing the .txt list UTF-8 encoding for Mac, Linux, Windows;
- Making sure the file names also **do not** contain special characters.

Still, I always get the same error:

## awk: lines 5 and 13: unexpected character 0xe2

### There are no special characters in the word list itself

#### These are the lines 5 and 13 in the awk script (maybe the special character is '$'?):

```
INCLUDE[$1]=1
if ($1 in INCLUDE) print >> outfile
```

*Any help would greatly appreciated.
Also, I am student and just a beginner with Word Embeddings and Vectors.*

Thank Youuu!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't unexpected characters in your input, it's unexpected characters in your script, probably DOS line endings added by whatever editor you used to create it. See [Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it) for how to identify and handle those. And no, `$` is not an unexpected character.

Aside from the problem you're asking about, your awk script has multiple issues:

```
BEGIN{                                     # 1

 infile = "adjectives.txt"
 while (getline < infile > 0) {            # 2
   INCLUDE[$1]=1                           # 3
 } 
 close(infile)
 
 infile = "cc.en.300.vec"
 outfile = "fasttextvectors_adjectives.txt"
 system("rm " outfile)                      # 4
 while (getline < infile > 0) {             # 2 again
   if ($1 in INCLUDE) print >> outfile      # 5
 } 
 close(infile)
 close(outfile)
}
```

The issues with the above are:

1. The main issue is that you wrote your script as if you were writing a C program and so have written while-getline loops when awk has that functionality already built in so you're missing a large part of the reason to use awk. Written in idiomatic awk your whole script should just be:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $1 in a' adjectives.txt cc.en.300.vec > fasttextvectors_adjectives.txt
```

2. `while (getline < infile > 0)` is ambiguous, different awks could
   read that as `while ((getline < infile) > 0)` or `while (getline < (infile > 0))` or something else. You MUST write a while-getline lop
   as `while ((getline < infile) > 0)` so you're guaranteed to be
   testing the return code from `getline`.
3. `INCLUDE[$1]=1` - don't use all upper case user-defined variable names so they don't clash with builtin variable names and so they don't look like you're using builtin variable names and so obfuscate your code. You also don't need to set the array content to `1` for how you're using it, just `INCLUDE[$1]` would be enough.
4. `system("rm " outfile)` is passing the value stored in `outfile` to the shell unquoted, it should be `system("rm \047" outfile "\047")` so what the shell sees is `rm 'fasttextvectors_adjectives.txt'`. You should consider just doing `printf "" > outfile` instead though if you just want to empty a file to avoid neding to create a subshell with `system()`.
5. awk is not shell and `>>` in awk does not mean the same as it does in `shell` (see the awk man page). Change `>>` to `>` and then you won't need to remove or otherwise initialize outfile before the loop unless you're worried about not overwriting a previous output file if there's no input this time.

Comment: Ed, it worked, I'm so excited! And you even explained everything that should be fixed. I'll totally read through the additional documents you mentioned. Thank you so much a zillion times, don't have words to thank enough, so I sent you a coffee!!!

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for the coffee :-)! To make sure it's clear, though, I'm not suggesting you fix the issues I enumerated for your current script, I'm recommending you through it away and just do `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $1 in a' adjectives.txt cc.en.300.vec > fasttextvectors_adjectives.txt` instead.

Comment: I used just this line and it worked perfectly. Thank you again!